# Merging two PDF documents into one

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

Can I merge two or more PDFs in asp.net? I know I can do Word and Excel files using interop. But can I merge PDFs?

Please suggest any suggestions or any links.

Comment: Take a look at here http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/36210-Merge-PDF-File-using-itextsharp-library.aspx it might helps you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/):

> iTextSharp is a C# port of iText, and open source Java library for
>   PDF generation and manipulation. It can be used to create PDF
>   documents from scratch, to convert XML to PDF (using the extra XFA
>   Worker DLL), to fill out interactive PDF forms, to stamp new content
>   on existing PDF documents, to split and **merge** existing PDF documents,
>   and much more.

[Here's an article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28283/Simple-NET-PDF-Merger) on how to do it.

Comment: can I only merge PDF using the code you suggested or any other formats can also be merged.? or from doc to pdf or .xls to pdf.? Can these operations can be done.?

Comment: Sorry, iTextSharp can only create PDFs from html, xml, or programmatically. You could turn doc into PDF using LibreOffice using the method described here: http://kgsspot.blogspot.ca/2011/09/convert-doc-to-pdf-in-command-line.html

Comment: @Ankur Please be aware that this merging routine is not the optimal merging code for iText(Sharp). `PdfWriter` is intended for the creation of new documents. For copying pages from a collection of already existing source documents you should use `PdfCopy.` Cf. the sample [Concatenate.cs](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter06&ex=Concatenate) from the book [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/).

Comment: @Ryan Weir: For some PDF I am getting this error " PdfReader not opened with owner password ". Please help.

Comment: @Ankur: I just checked and you're correct, in newer versions of iTextSharp the `unethicalreading` property you mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11991353/808532 isn't available anymore. Try downgrading the version of iTextSharp used in your project to 4.0.3 as seen at http://www.opensubscriber.com/message/itext-questions@lists.sourceforge.net/7709373.html - hopefully you don't use any features that are newer than this version. Worst case is for encrypted PDFs you detect the exception on them and use the old library.

Comment: @RyanWeir : After downloading it, how can I go about my error.?

Comment: @Ankur you need to set `PDFReader.unethicalreading = true` before trying to open the reader. If you need more help, I suggest posting this as a new question along with your code sample since this discussion is taking place in the wrong location here.

Comment: @RyanWeir : Ok I will try and will do accordingly. Thanks..!!

Comment: @RyanWeir : Done..!! Now the password error is not there..!!

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
using iTextSharp.text;
//Call this method in main with parameter
public static void MergePages(string outputPdfPath, string[] lstFiles)
{
    PdfReader reader = null;
    Document sourceDocument = null;
    PdfCopy pdfCopyProvider = null;
    PdfImportedPage importedPage;
    sourceDocument = new Document();
    pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(sourceDocument, 
    new System.IO.FileStream(outputPdfPath, System.IO.FileMode.Create));
    sourceDocument.Open();
    try
    {
        for (int f = 0; f < lstFiles.Length - 1; f++)
        {
            int pages = 1; 
            reader = new PdfReader(lstFiles[f]);
            //Add pages of current file
            for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
            {
                importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(importedPage);
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        sourceDocument.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```