# PdfReader not opened with owner password error in iText

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

With reference to this

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524857/merging-pdf-in-asp-net-c-sharp/17525948?noredirect=1#comment25485091_17525948
```

question of mine, I have user IText for merging the pdf documents. I am getting `" PdfReader not opened with owner password "` for some files. Any suggestions

Comment: Open it with the owner password?

Comment: @astander : I don't have any password for the PDF file.

Comment: @Ankur Not having the password means not being entitled to do what you try to do.

Comment: @Ankur If you are entitled, though, and merely forgot the owner password or the permissions should allow the operation in question, you might be interested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17694943/1729265).

Comment: @mkl I have the same issue, I have no password and the PDF opens nicely in all PDF readers I have (Acrobat, Foxit, Chrome), but fails with this message in iText.

Comment: Have you tried the trick I pointed to in my latest comment? If you did and it did not work, please supply the PDF in question.

Answer (score 90):

Add this code after PdfReader definition

**PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;**

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm

Not sure why it would be unethical to open a file via iTextSharp if I can open it otherwise without any warning or issues :)

Comment: for Itext7 the function is as follows: var reader = iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader) and then reader.SetUnethicalReading(true);

Answer (score 19):

For iText 7 it is

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(PATH + name + ".pdf");
pdfReader.setUnethicalReading(true);
```

See also:
   [itext7-how-decrypt-pdf-document-owner-password](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/manipulating-existing-pdfs/itext7-how-decrypt-pdf-document-owner-password)

Comment: Don't forget that the `PdfReader` is disposable and it should be disposed afterwards or use the `using` statement

Comment: for c# you need an uppercase method name so:

PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(PATH + name + ".pdf");
pdfReader.SetUnethicalReading(true);