# Itext7 Object reference error when merging pdf

Tags: c#, itext7

Getting a mysterious null ref error using itext7.  Everything was working fine before.  The PDF I'm reading looks normal.

```
 var sr1 = new MemoryStream(data);
 rdr = new PdfReader(sr1);
 // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691013/pdfreader-not-opened-with-owner-password-error-in-itext
 rdr.SetUnethicalReading(true);
 pdf = new PdfDocument(rdr);
 var pages = pdf.GetNumberOfPages();
 merger.Merge(pdf, 1, pages);
```

The only recent change was to add that call to SetUnethicalReading, which fixed one issue.
The PDF is fine, data has plenty of bytes.  'merger' is not null, nor is 'pdf'.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfOutline..ctor(String title, PdfDictionary content, PdfOutline parent)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfCatalog.ConstructOutlines(PdfDictionary outlineRoot, IDictionary`2 names)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfCatalog.GetOutlines(Boolean updateOutlines)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument.GetOutlines(Boolean updateOutlines)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfPage.GetOutlines(Boolean updateOutlines)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument.CopyPagesTo(IList`1 pagesToCopy, PdfDocument toDocument, Int32 insertBeforePage, IPdfPageExtraCopier copier)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument.CopyPagesTo(IList`1 pagesToCopy, PdfDocument toDocument, IPdfPageExtraCopier copier)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument.CopyPagesTo(IList`1 pagesToCopy, PdfDocument toDocument)
   at iText.Kernel.Utils.PdfMerger.Merge(PdfDocument from, IList`1 pages)
   at iText.Kernel.Utils.PdfMerger.Merge(PdfDocument from, Int32 fromPage, Int32 toPage)
```

Comment: Looks like an error in the PDF.

Comment: I can read the pdf. What should i be looking for?

Comment: You should inspect the internal structure of the pdf. According to the stack trace there seems to be an issue in the outline structure.